# ANTLR3 mutually left-recursive Rule

Tags: recursion, antlr, antlr3, left-recursion

Every solution I found on SO was "switch to ANTLR4" which isn't really an option because I am using `antlr4ruby` (which is ANTLR3, the 4 is meant as "for").

I want to build a rule for property access, it should match something like this:

```
variable
variable.property
variable.prop.prop
etc.
```

here's what I have:

```
variable: NAME -> ^(VARIABLE NAME) | variable DOT NAME -> ^(ACCESS variable NAME);
```

(`VARIABLE` and `ACCESS` are parser tokens for use later, `NAME` is a kind of string).

This is obviously left-recursive, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion#Removing_left_recursion may help.

Comment: that doesn't work because I need the inverted result; for `a.b.c` the AST should be `(A c (A b a))` not `(A a (A b c))`.